# Rename file name between two points

Tags: scripting, apple

I am looking for a way to rename a batch of videos by remove text between two points. Specifically I would like to remove everything after the 6th character, to the last "LabelMe--".

`0001--LabelMe--A005_01241110_C001--LabelMe-- --Interview--Man in library.mov`

`0002--LabelMe--A005_01241110_C002--LabelMe-- --Broll--Man looking at books.mov`

`0003--LabelMe--A005_01241111_C003--LabelMe-- --Broll--messed up--LabelMe-- --Broll--Sitting at table.mov`

I am trying to do this using Apple's Automator Services. Right-click on a bunch of files and select the service to clean up the name. I found one piece of code but am not sure I am using it correctly.

```
for f in "$@"
do 
    echo sed -e 's/\(--LabelMe).*\(LabelMe--)/\1\2/'
done
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of questions on this site about renaming files using shell loops like that, and a couple about using `sed` for that. (e.g. [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420927/batch-rename-files-to-a-sequential-numbering), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46923/how-to-rename-files-using-sed))

You'll need to pass the filename to `sed` with a pipe and use command substitution to catch the result, so something like this:

```
mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed -e '...' )"
```

The `sed` command you used needs a bit of fixing: For one, you've quoted the opening parenthesis but not the closing ones, so the grouping won't work. Also, I'm not sure why you'd like to put the `LabelMe` snippets back to the file name. If you want to remove them instead, just skip the grouping and the `\N` references:

```
's/--LabelMe.*LabelMe--//'
```

So in full:

```
for f in "$@"
do 
    mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed -e 's/--LabelMe.*LabelMe--//' )"
done
```

Another way would be to use the shell's parameter substitution to do the same. The substitution `${par/pattern/replacement}` is nonstandard, but supported in many shells:

```
for f in "$@"
do 
    mv "$f" "${f/--LabelMe*LabelMe--/}"
done
```

(note that's not a regex, so the syntax for "anything" is just `*`, and not `.*`)

Comment: That is amazing! Worked perfectly. This is a great way to start my day. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use (perl) rename. I don't know about Apple, but Linux distros mostly ship with two versions of rename. Perl rename is the more powerful one.

Firstly, run the command with the `-n` flag, which does a "dry-run", and makes no changes.

```
$ rename 's/(.{6}).*LabelMe--/$1/' 000* -n
0001--LabelMe--A005_01241110_C001--LabelMe-- --Interview--Man in library.mov -> 1110_C --Interview--Man in library.mov
0002--LabelMe--A005_01241110_C002--LabelMe-- --Broll--Man looking at books.mov -> 1110_C --Broll--Man looking at books.mov
0003--LabelMe--A005_01241111_C003--LabelMe-- --Broll--messed up--LabelMe-- --Broll--Sitting at table.mov -> messed --Broll--Sitting at table.mov
```

Once you are happy with the result, run it for real, i.e. `rename 's/(.{6}).*LabelMe--/$1/' 000*`

#### Explanation

- `rename 's/foo/bar/' 000*`: This format will search for the `foo` regex and replace it with `bar`. It will operate on all files matching the glob `000*`.
- `(.{6}).*LabelMe--`: This is the regex that you are searching for. You are looking for six of any character `.{6}`, which you put into a capturing group `(.{6})`. After this, you can have any characters `.*`, before finding `LabelMe--`.
- `$1`: This is what you will replace the above string with. `$1` refers to the contents of the matching group `(.{6})` above. The rest will not be replaced, i.e. you delete everything after the first six character up to and including `LabelMe--`.